# Solr 11 on typo3 10.4 not sorting

Tags: solr, typo3, typoscript

I'm indexing a table where I have a date attribute and I want to sort the result by this date value by default using this typoscript file.

This sortBy property of solr in typo3 is not working on my typoscript file but it does on the solr plugin.
https://docs.typo3.org/p/apache-solr-for-typo3/solr/main/en-us/Configuration/Reference/TxSolrSearch.html#query-sortby

```
plugin.tx_solr {
    search {



        query.sortBy = date_intS desc
        #This will not sort my index result but the same property on the solr plugin configuration will
        


        initializeWithEmptyQuery = 1
        showResultsOfInitialEmptyQuery = 1
        faceting = 1
        faceting {
            facets {
                Year {
                    label = Year
                    field = dod_intS
                }
            }
        }
    }
    index.queue {
        obituary = 1
        obituary {
            table = tx_myext_domain_model_obituary
            additionalWhereClause = deleted = 0 AND hidden = 0
            fields {
                title = COA
                title {
                    432 = TEXT
                    432.field = person
                }

                image_intS = SOLR_RELATION
                image_intS {
                    localField = image
                }

                dod_intS = TEXT
                dod_intS {
                    field = dod
                    data = date:U
                    strftime = %Y
                }

                date_intS = TEXT
                date_intS {
                    field = dod
                }

                condolences_intS = TEXT
                condolences_intS {
                    field = condolences
                }

                candles_intS = TEXT
                candles_intS {
                    field = candles
                }

                url = TEXT
                url {
                    typolink.parameter = {$pages.PIDs.myext.detailPid}
                    typolink.additionalParams = some_parameters
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But this will work. Don't know what's my problem here.

[image]

Comment: While I was posting I thought that maybe there was another typoscript file setting sortby, and there was. My site package as a sortBy property that is overriding the new one on my typoscript's extension.

Comment: But still... I don't understand yet how typoscript works so I don't know how to avoid this.

Comment: TypoScript is like a big associative PHP array containing some configuration values. That's why overriding is possible. But that's also why you should care about the order of setting key-value pairs or including different files setting the same key in TS. Besides this simple array thing, TS has some specialties like cObjects which allows to set "dynamic" values.